# AnsiPos or Pos does not match result in Delphi

Tags: delphi, substring

I cannot find out why this happen. On windows I have a txt file from which I read first line with text `'[směr:A->B]'`.

I thet my code with debugger. I use breakpoints so I see, that the result of `AnsiPos(line, '[sm')` is 0. Why? I suppost to get 1. But I tried to search for `AnsiPos(line, 'sm')` or just `AnsiPos(line, 'm')` and still not positive result. Why? I tried `Pos()` too. Should I use different function? What I missed?

```
readln(f,line);
if line[1]='[' then
begin;
  if line[2]='s' then
     if AnsiPos(line, '[sm') > 0 then
        begin
          if AnsiPos(line, 'B->A') > 0 then
            smerTestu := 'B'
          else
            smerTestu := 'A';
        end;
end;
```

Comment: you have a semicolon after the first `begin;`

Comment: You have the arguments to `AnsiPos` (and `Pos`) the wrong way around.

Comment: @guido so what?

Comment: @MartynA: Thank you this helped!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan so nothing, its just useless and might be confusing for some

Comment: Without that explanation the asker might think your comment was addressing the question

Answer (score 1):

From [System.Pos](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Pos), it is stated that the function:

> ```
> function Pos(const SubStr, Str: _ShortStr; Offset: Integer): Integer;
> function Pos(const SubStr, Str: UnicodeString; Offset: Integer): Integer; overload;
> function Pos(const SubStr, Str: _WideStr; Offset: Integer): Integer; overload;
> function Pos(const SubStr, Str: _RawByteStr; Offset: Integer): Integer;
> ```

is defined as:

> Locates a substring in a given string.
>
> The Pos method returns the index of the first occurence of Substr in Str, starting the search at Offset.
>
> This method returns zero if Substr is not found or Offset is invalid (for example, if Offset exceeds the String length or is less than 1).
>
> The Offset argument is optional. Offset is set to 1 by default, if no value for Offset is specified it takes the default value to start the search from the beginning.

---

In your code, you have mixed up the order of parameters `Str` and `SubStr`.

The `AnsiPos()` function works the same way.